# What are the interaction energies/chemical potential values for the cytoplasm - protein interactions within the cytoplasm?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, theoretical-biology, computational-model, protein-interaction

I'm trying to simulate phase separation in a biological based system using a Cahn Hilliard model. I have 3 components, they are 2 theoretical enzymes and the cytoplasm. I have found plenty of sources describing the interaction energies/chemical potential/free energy for protein-protein interactions, however, I cannot seem to find any of these values for cytoplasm interaction with proteins. Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if I am not being specific enough. Thank you!